# Passing a class to functions complications

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, self

I am writing a python program with tkinter but I ran into some complications where I don't know how I should deal with.

UPDATE: functional code to demonstrate the problem

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Schedule')
        self.label.pack()

        self.mtp_enter = False
        self.enter_small_shifts = False

        self.Button_Frame = Button_Frame(self)
        self.widgets = self.Button_Frame.New()
        self.Button_Frame.pack()

    def toggle_enter_small_shifts():
        if self.enter_small_shifts == False:
            if self.mtp_enter == True:
                self.toggle_mtp_enter()
            self.label.configure(text='MTP')
            self.enter_small_shifts = True
        else:
            self.label.configure(text='schedule')
            self.enter_small_shifts = False

    def toggle_mtp_enter():
        if self.mtp_enter == False:
            if self.enter_small_shifts == True:
                self.toggle_enter_small_shifts()
            self.label.configure(text='MTP')
            self.mtp_enter = True
        else:
            self.label.configure(text='schedule')
            self.mtp_enter = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root= tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("Shelter Schedule Maker")
    app = MainApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()

class Button_Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
    def New(self):
        widgets = {}
        toggle_enter_mtp = tk.Button(self, text='Enter MTP\'s', command=app.toggle_mtp_enter, width=15)
        widgets['enter mtp'] = toggle_enter_mtp
        toggle_enter_mtp.pack()
        toggle_enter_small_shifts = tk.Button(self, text='Enter small shift\'s', command=app.toggle_enter_small_shifts, width=15)
        widgets['enter small shifts'] = toggle_enter_small_shifts
        toggle_enter_small_shifts.pack()
        return widgets
```

In conclusion: before `MainApp` I need to define `Button_Frame`, before `Button_Frame` I need the `MainApp` instance, before the `Mainapp` instance I need the `MainApp` class. There is a full circle.

How should I restruture this to work?

Comment: Rather than code snippets, please try to paste a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is "There are also other functions in the class which do use 'self' as an argument", but as SiHa says, it's impossible to help without seeing more of the context.

Comment: Thanks, I made a MCV example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define all methods in the class to be instance methods, and use `self` within the class and `app` outside the class:

```
class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    ...
    def toggle_mtp_enter(self):
        if self.enter_mtp == False:
            if self.enter_small_shifts == True:
                self.toggle_enter_small_shifts()
            self.shift_buttons_widgets = self.shift_buttons.Activate_mtp()
    ...
app = MainApp(...)
...
toggle_enter_mtp = tk.Button(self, text='Enter MTP\'s', command=app.toggle_mtp_enter, width=15)
...
```

Ideally, `Button_Frame` shouldn't rely on a global variable `app`. You're already passing in an instance of the app when you create `Button_frame` (as `parent`), so you can do something like this:

```
class Button_Frame(tk.Frame):
    ...
    def New(self):
        ...
        toggle_enter_mtp = tk.Button(..., command=self.parent.toggle_mtp_enter, ...)
        ...
        toggle_enter_small_shifts = tk.Button(..., command=self.parent.toggle_enter_small_shifts, ...)
        ...
```

You also need to define all of your classes before creating the app:

```
class MainApp(...):
    ...
class Button_Frame(...):
    ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but when I write it like that I get the error that MainApp isn't defined.

Comment: @Bob: simple fix: define `MainApp` first.

Comment: But then I get an error because MainApp uses the class in which the button is located, which it then doesn't find.
I'm probably structuring something wrong here. As requested by others I have made a functional code so you can see the whole picture, updates as per your last idea.

Comment: @Bob: define all of your classes before creating instances of any of the classes.

Comment: Now the class `Button_Frame` crashes because it uses the instance of `MainApp` (in the command for the button) which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Bob: I've updated my answer. Your latest problem is one (of many) reasons why it's bad to rely on global variables. It sounds complicated, but it's really not: define classes before using them, and if an object needs a reference to some other object, give it (pass it in) to that object.

Comment: It took some time to restructure all of the bindings and things but Bryan, you are my hero. Now I feel like my program makes way more sense.